# JavaFX - Getting icons of the default Alerts (ERROR,WARNING,INFORMATION)

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I want to change the Icon of TextInputDialog... Instead of show the CONFIRMATION icon I want to display the WARNING icon. But how to receive it without inserting any downloaded/drawed image?

```
TextInputDialog dia = new TextInputDialog();
      dia.setTitle("Wait for input");
      dia.setHeaderText(titleString);
      dia.setContentText(messageString);
      dia.setGraphic(/*WARNING_ICON*/);
      Optional<String> result = dia.showAndWait();
          if (result.isPresent())
             /*do something juicy*/
          else
             /*do nothing*/
```

I already tried `dia.setGraphic( new Alert(AlertType.WARNING).getGraphic());` but that doesn't work. The Icon disappears in this case.

Comment: the icon is only available after styling, so a quick hack is a `alert.applyCSS();` before accessing the graphic

Comment: .. cleaner: style the input dialog directly, something like `inputDialog.getDialogPane().getStyleClass().addAll("alert", "warning")`